# Adding results to Eloquent according to some conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table Product and I need to get related products. This is how I should get related products:

Get 12 products that have the same model_id

If I got less than 12 products then keep what I got and add Products with the same category_id until I complete 12 products.

I was thinking about something like this but its not working.

```
$products = Product::first();
$relatedProducts = Product::query();
$relatedProducts = $relatedProducts->where('model_id', $product->model_id)->take(12);
$tmp_total = $relatedProducts->count();
if($tmp_total < 12) {
    $relatedProducts->where('category_id', $product->category_id)->take(12);
}
return $relatedProducts->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Any `where` clauses you add are added to the original query.

You need a new query for the second one:

```php
$product = Product::first();

$related = Product::where('model_id', $product->model_id)->take(12)->get();

if ($related->count() < 12) {
    $related = $related->merge(
        Product::where('category_id', $product->category_id)
               ->where('model_id', '!=', $product->model_id)
               ->take(12 - $related->count())
               ->get()
    );
}

return $related;
```

Comment: Just add another where to exclude current model_id on the 2nd query so you don't get duplicates from the 1st.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = Product::first();
$products = Product::where('model_id', $product->model_id)
            ->take(12)
            ->get();
$remain = 12 - $products->count();
if ($remain > 0){
    $additions = Product::where('category_id', $product->category_id)
                ->take($remain)
                ->get();
    $products->merge($additions);
}
return $products;
```